# castle activerecord rewrite sql

Tags: castle-activerecord

is there anyway to intercept the sql query before it is sent to the database and rewrite it using castle active record ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up an interceptor and use `OnPrepareStatement` to modify the generated SQL. See [this example](http://www.davesquared.net/2008/08/modifying-sql-generated-by-nhibernate.html).